# Plotting symbolic function in MatLab

Tags: matlab, plot

I've some problems in plotting a symbolic function in MatLab: for example when I try to plot the function f with ezplot, where:

```
f = 9/2 - ((2*x)/5 - 2/5)*(x/3 - 17/6) - x
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using findstr
Inputs must be character arrays.

Error in ezplot>ezplot1 (line 442)
    if (isa(f, 'inline') && ~isempty(findstr(char(f), '=')))

Error in ezplot (line 145)
                [hp, cax] = ezplot1(cax, f{1}, vars, labels, args{:});

Error in sym/ezplot (line 61)
   h = ezplot(fhandle(f));
```

I've tried to convert the symbolic function f in the char form but it returns an analogous error:

```
Error using findstr
Inputs must be character arrays.

Error in ezplot>ezplot1 (line 442)
    if (isa(f, 'inline') && ~isempty(findstr(char(f), '=')))

Error in ezplot (line 145)
                [hp, cax] = ezplot1(cax, f{1}, vars, labels, args{:});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you define your function as an anonymous function:

```
myfun = @(x)  4.5 - (((2*x)/5 - 2/5)*(x/3 - 17/6) - x);

figure
ezplot(myfun)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't use this expression since I've a given vector of symbolic expression like the one I posted before.

Comment: oh shoot I see sorry then.

Answer (score 1):

You must have some problem with you function definition. Perhaps `x` has been defined incorrectly?

The following works, at least in Matlab 2010b. It defines `f` as a **symbolic function** of the symbolic variable `x`:

```
>> clear all
>> syms x
>> f = 9/2 - ((2*x)/5 - 2/5)*(x/3 - 17/6) - x;
>> ezplot(f)
```

The following is also valid. It defines `f` as a **string**:

```
>> clear all
>> f = '9/2 - ((2*x)/5 - 2/5)*(x/3 - 17/6) - x';
>> ezplot(f)
```

Comment: I defined both f and the variable x as syms in my program!

Comment: Well, I think this is black magic but I repeat it many times, clear the workspaces after and before the codes but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why the `ezplot` command doesn't work with my Matlab 2012b, so I had to go with a brutal solution like this :(

```
syms x
f = 9/2 - ((2*x)/5 - 2/5)*(x/3 - 17/6) - x;

k = 0.1;
x_p = 0:k:10;
y_p = subs(f,x,x_p);
plot(x_p,y_p)
```